# How to Pretend to be an website in curl PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, http-status-code-401

so I built a scraper with PHP - curl. So I can build my API and integrate in my application.
The problem is that I am getting blocked by the website in just one page.

What my scraper does:

1. First it goes to the website that have an iframe ( and this iframe have an iframe inside, which I want to get the src of it).
2. When it get the first iframe url, it sends a curl request to the iframe src, but the problem is that the site is blocking any request from websites other than their website. So I get blocked. Is there any solution to pretend being the URL of this website.

BTW, this is the URL of the website [here](https://okanime.tv/animes/yakusoku-no-neverland-2nd-season/episodes/yakusoku-no-neverland-2nd-season-001-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A9). You can inspect the website iframe and see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry buddy! you can’t. If it was possible, I would pretend to be your bank and steal your bank credentials! crazy, right?

you can act like a reverse proxy, for example:
I am the user and you are the interface.
I come to your website, `foo.com` and search for `google.com`.
you can send a curl to `google.com`, get the response from `google.com` and show it to me.
I see `foo.com` address in my browser but actually I’m browsing `google.com`.
and `google.com` thinks that your server(`foo.com`) is using it’s site. not me.
and if you get a lot of users, `google.com` will probably block your server as an attacker server.

read about CORS and Reverse Proxy for more information.

Comment: thanks for you clear answer, just a question if I cant do what that, then can I pretend to be a browser?

Comment: about that, read the edited answer